# Image not loading in css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem in bootstrap/css. I want to load image from source folder and I typed in css this code:

```
background: url('../img/home.jpg') no-repeat;
```

But it doesn't show in my home section on the page.

https://codepen.io/write/image-not-loading

Comment: Your code works, probably you don't see it because the element doesn't have a height.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try

```
    background-size: cover;
```

Or as  ZohirSalak CeNa said, resizing your element that is containing the background image unless it is your body.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your Title</title>
    </head>
    <body class="your-class">

    </body>
</html
```

**CSS**

```
.your-class {

    background-image: url('../img/home.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}
```

Also, Make sure you have the correct path to your image

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I am beginner so I know very little. I tried what you suggested and it did not work. I followed instructions from Udemy course, did everything like the guy in the video but still the image doesn't load.

Comment: @PetarScepanovic is your CSS file connect to your HTML file correctly?  Your code is totally legit and works, just make sure it is connected right and has the correct path to the image

Comment: yes, everything is connected. Any kind of change in html or css is visible on my page. Except the image. Also it has correct path to the image. This is very strange

Comment: Can you create another codepen with your code in it? I just now created a codepen account

Comment: I got a random image address from the internet ( https://images.pexels.com/photos/370799/pexels-photo-370799.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350 ) and put in in the url and it worked fine. You have the image you want to use downloaded right? If you do for now go to it and right click on it and click copy path and then paste it in the url, try that. If it is on the web you can right click and get image address and paste it in the url. Tell me if that works.

Comment: I finally found out what was the problem. I renamed the image file to image.jpg and I thought the name of the file was home.jpg. But actually the name was home.jpg.jpg. How silly...Thank you for your help. Can I ask you if I get stuck again?

Comment: Haha, We all do that every once in a while! Sure Mate! I would be glad to help if you are stuck. Do you have discord or something we can private message on?

Comment: Of course :) I just created profile on discord, username Chilolo

Comment: Okay Cool! Just friend request me my name and Id is Zuke76#8677 go to direct messages and add friend :D